# wiki links (irc bot)

Tags: python, bots, irc

I've created an IRC Bot for http://www.rsplayers.wikia.com/ that successfully connects to the channel and has some basic commands, but I've been stuck on this one part which allows you to link around the site.  Wiki links are basically [[Link]], nothing fancy.  Currently commands can only be done in one def, here is an example say command:

```
def say(self, sender, info, cmd):
    return "PRIVMSG %s :%s\n" % (info[2], cmd[1])
```

info[2] is the channel the command was issued in and cmd[1] is anything after the !say.  The commands are listed like this too:

```
self.USER_CMD = {'!say': self.say, '!test': self.test, '!time': self.time, '!help': self.help, '!8ball': self.eightball}
```

I don't have much (any) idea how I can create this, so I need help.

**EDIT**: As asked in the comments to be more specific:  Whenever someone typed in [[Brakets]] it will return with a link back to the rsplayers wiki website.  An example being:

> ( Nick ) [[Main Page]]
>
> ( Bot ) http://www.rsplayers.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: This question is not specific enough.  Create what, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want to append the link to the end of the wiki, then do just that.  If you're looking to ensure there is an actual page, that requires more work, basically check for http status code 200 or some such thing.

To just append the command, you should strip the brackets, titlecase everything and insert underscores where spaces are, as that seems to be the scheme used on that wiki.

```
def say_wiki(self, sender, info, cmd):
    home = 'http://www.rsplayers.wikia.com/wiki/'
    link = '_'.join(cmd[1].title().split())
    return 'PRIVMSG %s :%s%s\r\n' % (info[2], home, link)
```

If you need to support whether or not the link was valid, you can use urllib.

```
import urllib

def say_wiki(self, sender, info, cmd):
    home = 'http://www.rsplayers.wikia.com/wiki/'
    link = '_'.join(cmd[1].title().split())
    page = urllib.urlopen(home + link)
    if 200 == page.getcode():
        return 'PRIVMSG %s :%s%s\r\n' % (info[2], home, link)
    else:
        return 'PRIVMSG %s :%s is not a valid page\r\n' % (info[2], cmd[1])
```

Though there may be a better way to achieve this.